# Adding an 'if' statement to an AJAX process in Webmatrix

Tags: sql, razor, webmatrix

Below is my code which processes an AJAX request.

Currently, when I select an **area** on my form page, it will send a "getresort" value to this **process** page, and everything works fine.

The issue comes when I don't want to search for a specific area, and instead want to display ALL resorts in ALL areas. If I select "all" in the form, it doesn't submit a value, so the WHERE clause fails as it can't get the request from the query string.

I'm assuming I need an 'if' statement in there somewhere, to check if the query string is blank, so that it runs a SQL statement that removes the WHERE AreaName = @0 part.

Where should this 'if' statement live?

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");

var getresortval = Request.QueryString["resval"];
var type = Request.QueryString["type"];
var res = Request.QueryString["res"];
var area = Request.QueryString["area"];

var allresorts = "SELECT ResortID, ResortName FROM ResortInfo WHERE AreaName = @0";
var qallresorts = db.Query(allresorts, getresortval);

if(type == "resortupdate") {
    foreach(var row in qallresorts){
    <option value='@row.ResortID'>@row.ResortName</option>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");

var getresortval = Request.QueryString["resval"];
var type = Request.QueryString["type"];
var res = Request.QueryString["res"];
var area = Request.QueryString["area"];

var allresorts = "SELECT ResortID, ResortName FROM ResortInfo";
if(!getresortval.IsEmpty()){
    allresorts += " WHERE AreaName = @0";
}
var qallresorts = db.Query(allresorts, getresortval);

if(type == "resortupdate") {
    foreach(var row in qallresorts){
    <option value='@row.ResortID'>@row.ResortName</option>
    }
}
```

Comment: This works absolutely perfect. In fact, i have since tweeked my code, so that is checks the querystring for the value 'any' (add added that value to the any option in my form), but it works on the same premise.